# Importing a mysql database after drop filling up limited / in /tmp deleted file - A problem?

Tags: mysql, partitioning, mysql-5.1, centos

I'm importing a fairly large set of databases into a system which has a / partition only 10GB large. After a previous failed import, I dropped the database, but noticed /var/lib/mysql didn't exactly empty out - Now I'm watching the root partition fill up with this file:

```
$ sudo lsof / | grep deleted
mysqld    53058     mysql   41u   REG  253,0 951599104   5523 /tmp/MLR7HVLj (deleted)
```

This file is growing large enough (2GB) that I'm starting to worry that it'll crash my system. Is this a known problem (Old centos 6 mysql version 5.1) with trying to import a database after it's been dropped already, and is mysql aware of limited space in the partition it's filling up with a deleted file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST` -- there is probably a complex query running, creating a huge tmp table.

Kill that process (go into mysql commandline tool, do `SHOW PROCESSLIST` to get the pid, then do kill, in the tool, with that number.)

Then scratch your head as to why it is taking so much room.  A likely case:

```
SELECT ... FROM a, b;
```

and failing to restrict how `a` and `b` should be `JOINed`.  This is called a `CROSS JOIN`; it can be huge.

Comment: I found out what it was checking that, and it turned out to just be the insert query running while that was going up. I also eliminated that it was 'deleting' the old dropped tables by restarting it after deleting everything in /var/lib/mysql and reinstalling mysql again - No luck there either, but now I've managed to allocate way more space to that partition, which should alleviate the issue of it growing on that on a sheer insert operation from a particularly large dumpfile.

Comment: Thank the --ignore feature for me being able to continue without this taking forever to import

Comment: But how much of the data is missing?

Comment: Absolutely none after taking the careful, conservative option and redoing it from the start, getting replication right this time around on top of it